# problem trying to build my app in ionic cordova

Tags: android, node.js, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried to build my app and I am receiving an error. I am using:

- ionic cordova build android
- node version: 12.13.0

Error Below

```
C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido>ionic cordova build android --verbose
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe', tty: true, windows: true } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'android' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, project: null, '--': [] } +4ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic 1 (ionic1) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: 'C:\\Users\\ville\\Documents\\gobus-hibrido\\ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'ionic1' } +1ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: 'C:\\Users\\ville\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath: 'C:\\Users\\ville\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic', execPath: 'C:\\Users\\ville\\Documents\\gobus-hibrido', version: '5.4.4' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: 'C:\\Users\\ville\\Documents\\gobus-hibrido\\config.xml', package.json: 'C:\\Users\\ville\\Documents\\gobus-hibrido\\package.json') +0ms
  ionic:lib:build build options: {
  ionic:lib:build   '--': [],
  ionic:lib:build   engine: 'cordova',
  ionic:lib:build   platform: 'android',
  ionic:lib:build   project: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   verbose: false,
  ionic:lib:build   type: 'ionic1'
  ionic:lib:build } +0ms
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova build' [ 'android', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +8ms

 ionic-v1.cmd build
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulpfile: C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido\gulpfile.js +0ms
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulp: C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido\node_modules\gulp\index.js +4ms
[11:20:02] Cannot load gulp: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulpfile: C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido\gulpfile.js +155ms
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulp: C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido\node_modules\gulp\index.js +1ms
[11:20:02] Cannot load gulp: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
[11:20:02] Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulpfile: C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido\gulpfile.js +4ms
  ionic:v1-toolkit:lib:gulp Using gulp: C:\Users\ville\Documents\gobus-hibrido\node_modules\gulp\index.js +1ms
[11:20:02] Cannot load gulp: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:after npm script. +461ms
 cordova.cmd build android --verbose
```

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>
> cordova.cmd build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

Comment: No code.  Nothing we can do.

Comment: Please provide the code that is failing.

Comment: Have you tried installing gulp by npm install -g gulp ?

Answer (score 0):

Please downgrade / switch to NodeJS 10, this is a known issue with NodeJS 12 and specific dependencies. Or dleete the lockfile (package-lock.json) and try it again.